# df.hist() is not returning plot of desired size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, axes

I am using df.hist() to get plots of all the columns in my DataFrame. The problem is that it is not displaying my plots in desired dimensions

I am using following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
df.hist()
plt.show()
```

it returns me with a grid of histograms but with a very small view along with a text

> <Figure size **720x864** with 0 Axes>

On increasing the size, suppose figsize=(20,24), *Doubled!*

it **still returns me with a grid of histograms of the same size**, however, the text in output correctly mentions the change,

> <Figure size **1440x1728** with 0 Axes>

What is going wrong here? And what is the simplest way to get my grid of histograms displayed in the size I request?

P.S. I checked for other plots for Series and columns and they are working fine by returning me plots of the size I mention in figsize.

The problem is with df.hist()

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the size to `hist`:

```
ax = df.hist(figsize=(10,12))
plt.show()
```

Comment: GREAT! Could you explain it a bit? why this worked and why df.hist() didn't?
Also, the labels are overlapping. Can u suggest soemthing with that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. It maybe a bug when `df.hist()` creates the sub-axis internally. `plt.tight_layout` would help with the overlapping of labels, or you need to increase figsize.

Comment: Can't thank you enough mate! Thanks a lot. This question has been bothering a lot of guys.